# Как избавиться дублирования кода в разных активити?

Tags: android, activity

Допустим есть основное активити, его тело описано в `main_activity_body`, в целом это выглядит так:

```
<include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <!-- MAIN Activity -->
        <include layout="@layout/main_activity_body" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/menu" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Я хочу создать второе активити, описываю его в файле `second_activity_body`, но, как мне его создать так чтоб не делать такого:

```
<include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <!-- SECOND Activity -->
        <include layout="@layout/second_activity_body" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/menu" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Это жесткое дублирование кода, как избежать этого, как сделать все поумнее?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте одну активити с `DrawerLayout` и несколько фрагментов в ней. При кликах по меню - меняются фрагменты.

Comment: Что значит `и несколько фрагментов в ней`? Для чего все активити в одно подключать? Приведите пример если вам не сложно

Comment: В официальной документации по Navigation Drawer, как раз [пример с фрагментами](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html). Про сами фрагменты почитайте [здесь](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html?hl=ru).